# Edit GeoJson file in asp.net core C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, geojson, edit, json-deserialization

I want to edit GeoJson file, which I put part of its lines here. How to edit in this way, I have to read the file and change the `Landuse` value using the code in the properties.

```
{"type":"FeatureCollection", "features": [
{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[45.882982627281955,35.98144306876872],[45.8830448154499,35.98142063110326],[45.883106013386524,35.98143674855534],[45.883177395327635,35.981590195979166],[45.88306057502328,35.98161790966196],[45.882982627281955,35.98144306876872]]]},"properties":{"Code":1,"Landuse":"مسکونی","Longitude":45.8830793043,"latitude":35.9815185013}},
{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[45.88321822952168,35.98143433703011],[45.88329577844585,35.981578778123584],[45.883184747057655,35.98160599975271],[45.883177395327635,35.981590195979166],[45.88313701140243,35.981503383976175],[45.883107851319025,35.981440699498734],[45.88321822952168,35.98143433703011]]]},"properties":{"Code":2,"Landuse":"مسکونی","Longitude":45.8832014571,"latitude":35.9815182472}},
...
]}
```

I converted the GeoJson file to C# classes using this [site](https://json2csharp.com/).
And the result is as follows

```
public class ConvertorJsonLayerDTO {
    public class Feature {
        public string type {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public Geometry geometry {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public Properties properties {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }

    public class Geometry {
        public string type {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public List<List<List<double>>> coordinates {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }

    public class Properties {
        public int Code {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public string Landuse {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public double Longitude {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public double latitude {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }

    public class Root {
        public string type {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public List<Feature>features {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }
}
```

Now I read the file in C# as follows:

```
var code = 2;
var Geojson = File.ReadAllText(Path);
var deserialize = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(Geojson);
```

Now, how do I make a blind move on this file and change the property whose code is 2 to the `Landuse` property value and update the file?
Please guide me. I will definitely share the result with you...Thankful

Comment: I'd recommend to use the `Use Pascal Case` option when generating the classes or to use a NuGet-package like: https://www.nuget.org/packages/geojson (Not mine)

Answer (score 1):

I'd recomend using `Linq`:

```
var feature = deserialize.features.FirstOrDefault(feature => feature.properties.Code == 2);
if (feature != null)
{
    feature.properties.Landuse = "new Landuse";
}
```

It gives you the first feature where `feature.properties.Code` is equal to `2` or it returns `null` if there is no feature with the code 2.

Comment: Our problem is exactly how to deserialize the file into a variable so that we can loop over that variable and edit it, and finally how to serialize and update the file.

Comment: Your approach was correct. The object is stored in `deserialize`. You can use it to loop through the features. To get back Json just use `var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(deserialize);`

Answer (score 0):

You could Try with JObject to avoid  unnecessary models/Properties for rest part of your file

```
var  str= System.IO.File.ReadAllText("path");
            var jobj= JObject.Parse(str);
            var  newjobj=   (JObject)jobj["SomeSection"]["ChildSection"];
            var obj = newjobj.ToObject<TargetObject>();
```

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5v9l6.png)

I did the same but got this error
I'm just looking for a solution to query a GeoJson file and edit the desired value and save it again.

Comment: you can't answer your question with question , you can edit your question